# Publish all users data onLogin

Tags: meteor

I've attached an additional field to my Meteor.users collection. It's a single piece of information to determine the stage the user is at during the registration process.I would like to publish it `onLogin` however my code below doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

Path: `imports/startup/server/onlogin.js`

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(user){
  Meteor.publish('userdata', function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id: user.user._id }, {
      fields: { myUniqueField: 1 }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: The actual users collection call Accounts. Try to run `Accounts.find({})` see if it works for you.

Comment: No, it's `Meteor.users`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server the publication shouldn't run in the callback of an event handler (`onLogin`). `this.userId` will give you the `_id` of the current logged in user.

```
Meteor.publish('userdata', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {
    fields: { myUniqueField: 1 }
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems like Meteor is your own domain on SO lately, well done :)

Comment: I wanted to run it in onLogin because i need all the data to come down the pipe at once where do I put this so it loads right away?

Comment: Or is that just the way meteor loads and there's nothing I can do about it

Comment: Normally you just set up publications with `Meteor.publish` and Meteor loads them on startup. They only *run* when the client subscribes so think of the triggering event as taking place on the client instead of the server.